# can to select primary value with relation many to many in strapi?

Tags: javascript, mysql, strapi

in strapi when create the relation with two section i need to select one item is primary add flug for this item primary ?
for example :

I expected it to be possible to choose between primary value relationships and add flug for this item is primary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BP5g.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Strapi by default does not support this